# What is the earliest instance of a film where none of the protagonists survive?

Tags: first-appearance

I was having a discussion about this with a colleague, who claimed that [*Evil Dead (1981)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083907/) was the first film he knew of that had all the main characters die off. However he forgot that Mia survives that film.

This got me thinking - what is the earliest film that has every single "good" character die before the end? Not just the "bad guys" winning, but a total wipe of the characters.

Comment: Interesting question.   Invasion of the Body Snatchers, (Donald Sutherland/Leonard Nimoy version), you never saw the last character die but it was implied.   Reservoir Dogs (does that count?).   On the Beach (1959) - been a long time since I saw it.   Do apocalyptic movies count?  That type of plot is quite rare.   Hamlet?   Romeo and Juliet?   (I'll stop now).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely [*All Quiet on the Western Front* (1930)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0020629/).  All of the main characters die during battle.

If you want a movie where *everyone* dies, it might be [*Beneath the Planet of the Apes* (1970)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065462/).  That movie ends with the destruction of Earth by a nuclear weapon.